# Zebra MC220K not working with local DNS server

Tags: wi-fi, android-10

I need help debugging something. My company recently purchased an `Zebra MC220K`, and it is unable to resolve internal DNS domains. I have tried all of the following:

1. Forget the network.
2. Enable / disable airplane mode.
3. Change the wifi configuration to 'static' and manually put in the DNS server that we use.
4. Install termux and doing a DNS lookup, which resulted in the correct ip should be referring to.
5. Factory reset the device.
6. Check a dozen other android devices (S8, S10, S20, Galaxy Tab, Google Pixel, etc), all of which work as expected.
7. Run an android 10 vm, which also works as expected.

I am at a loss, I have no clue why I am still getting `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` when using Chrome / Firefox / Edge / Samsung Internet / Brave / Opera. Literally any browser throws this error, clearly indicating something wrong in the software.

Are there any other tests I should perform, or do I just yeet back the product because it doesnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whoever is banging their head against a wall, turns out it is an actual Zebra issue. They do not use the DNS provided in the DHCP config and *always* default to another DNS resolver. The affected versions are OS build 10.16.10  LG44 or LG79.

If you require a hotpatch, feel free to reach out to their customer support, they will be able to provide one to you.